# Performance issues with CAST function

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, explain, cast, postgresql-performance

Observing this performance issue that can't be explained with `EXPLAIN` in a PostgreSQL 9.6 database.

There is currently a table `public`.`users`, which has a *cast* on it to output a record to `JSONb`.  (e.g. `SELECT u::jsonb FROM users u;`).

The database has grown in complexity and schemas, which a new schema (think module) has been added that adds a few things to the user accounts (via joins in the schema table).

To make the cast to `JSONb` consistant across the app, the `public`.`users` *cast* was refashioned to use a cast in a new schema called `catalogue`.  This way casting `public`.`users` will get additional properties from the `catalogue` schema in a transparent way to the user.  This was done so that the API Server doesn't need to know to use this/that schema, and I can leave my (reused) User API Controller the same.

The new [refashioned] *cast* returns the cast from `catalogue`.`users`, so basically the `public`'s *cast* function on `users` call a [SQL] function with the simple SQL command..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION catalogue.cast_user_jsonb_override(public.user)  RETURNS JSONb STABLE LANGUAGE sql
AS $$ 
 SELECT u::jsonb FROM catalogue.users u WHERE username = $1.username 
$$;
```

This way the casting `public`.`user` to `JSONb` will utilise the above cast without the user knowing.

**However**, for some reason calling the cast for `public`.`users` is slow, while calling the cast for `catalogue`.`users` is fast.

Calling...

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE SELECT u::jsonb FROM catalogue.users u;
....
Planning time: 0.046 ms
Execution time: 40.086 ms
```

while calling...

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE SELECT u::jsonb FROM catalogue.users u;
....
Planning time: 0.094 ms
Execution time: 1384.414 ms
```

or directly...

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE SELECT catalogue.cast_users_jsonb_override(u) FROM public.users u;
....
Planning time: 0.101 ms
Execution time: 1325.343 ms
```

If anything, the catalogue cast should be the slower one as is performs joins and the likes.

The [override] cast function is `STABLE` to help with performance, but it doesn't seem to do much.

*Any ideas as to why calling a function that executes a basic `SELECT` is slow, while calling the SQL itself is fast?* . I haven't tested it in any other postgresql version, and there isn't any priority to do an upgrade to v10 to test as there is currently a deadline on the release.

Answer (score 1):

Put `auto_explain` into `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgresql.conf` and restart PostgreSQL.

Set

```
auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on
auto_explain.log_analyze = on
auto_explain.log_buffers = on
```

in `postgresql.conf` (and reload).

Then run the slow query again.

This will log all SQL statements and their execution plan in the PostgreSQL log. Examine the plan for the statement run in your function. That should give you a clue.

The most likely explanation would be a missing index on `catalogue.users(username)`.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, will give that a try.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should reset all these parameters when you are done investigating. The sessings will slow you down considerably.

Comment: Hehe...thanks, will remember too.  I had some other debug out in the logs that filled my disk the other day with 1.7GB of logs.  (a quick gzip freed up 95% of that)